# R mean of one column based on another

Tags: r, selection

I have a matrix

```
     sex age height weight
[1,]   2   6  110     22
[2,]   1   2   84     12
[3,]   2   2   85     10
[4,]   1   6  108     20
[5,]   2   4  100     18
[6,]   1   4   98     16
```

How do I calculate mean height for sex = 2 (girls)
It should be simple but I can't find the answer.

Comment: `mean(data[data$sex==2,3])`

Comment: Please share your matrix in reproducible format. You can use dput().

Comment: While you are asking for the mean of just one of the factors, I suspect that you need or *will need* the mean of the other factor as well. That makes this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272. (Even if you don't eventually want the mean of `sex=1`, you can still take any of those solutions and subset.)

Comment: (BTW: that presumes that this should really be a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`. In this case it is not wrong to use a matrix instead, but it is perhaps against the normal flow of data in R that represents *observations* (rows) and *properties* of each observation (columns). If you were to convert your data with `as.data.frame`, any/all of the previously-linked answers should work.)